# How to load data within date range on Qlik Sense?

Tags: mysql, date, qliksense

I would like to load data within a defined date range on Qlik Sense.

When I load the data, I set it to be in the format below:

```
SET DateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY(WWW)';
```

I hope to use a where statement to limit the data where the column variable [Date] is within a date range.

However, the below statement placed after the LOAD columns FROM table statement did not work:

where [Date]<'30/11/2016(Wed)' and [Date]>'01/12/2015(Tue)'

May I know what is the syntax for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit a date in MySQL to a range, using the date bounds of the range alone is enough, i.e.

```
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-12' AND '2016-11-30'
```

Specifying the day of the week is redundant and unnecessary, because for example Novmeber 12, 2015 is always a Tuesday.

If your source date data has the format `dd/mm/YYYY` then you can use the [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to parse into a date.  After that, you can make the same comparison:

```
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN '2015-01-12' AND '2016-11-30'
```